# Const method accessing static variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static, constants

I apologize if this has been asked before. My search results did not turn up a similar question.

This is a conceptual question. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh(VS.80).aspx) and others as well:

> A constant member function cannot modify any data members or call any member functions that aren't constant

Why then are we allowed to access static member variables from a const method?

Comment: If you're only reading the member variables then you're not changing them and don't violate the const requirement right?

Comment: @Jay I can change it as well, not just read it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C++ standard says this about `const` member functions:

> If the member function is declared `const`, the type of this is `const X*`, [...]
>
> In a `const` member function, the object for which the function is called is accessed through a `const` access path; therefore, a `const` member function shall not modify the object and its non-static data members.

So you see that only non-static data members are part of the 'constness' of the member function.

However, I think that more importantly it indicates that a good way to understand what's going on with `const` member functions is that it makes the implicit `this` pointer a pointer to `const`.

Since static members don't need to be accessed via the `this` pointer (implicitly or explicitly), access to them isn't `const` qualified.

Comment: Thank you for very much for your response. After some thought I decided to check yours as the correct answer as it explains in more detail without leaving any doubt, especially the part: _".. a good way to understand what's going on..."_

Answer (score 13):

Because they are not part of the object.