# Why does this const member function modifies the static member data?

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following line of code from Eckel-Thining in C++

```
Class Obj{
    static int i,j;
    public:
    void f() const {cout<<i++<<endl;}
    void f() const {cout<<i++<<endl;}
};
int Obj::i=47;
int Obj::j=11;
```

Now it's written in Ecekl for const member functions that by declaring a member function const , we tell the compiler to refrain from modifying a class data. I understand that in some specific cases like mutable const and by explicitly casting away constness of this pointer , we can do away with that but here neither of the two are happening and i++ and j++ working fine. Why is it so?

Comment: Static members aren't part of the object.

Comment: But they are declared private to the class isn't it ? its only that they have one unique storage for all the objects .

Comment: Exactly, so they don't belong to any object. They exist before any objects are created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` is only for object (`this` pointer is `const`), modifying `static members` is allowed.

Comment: :Why is it so that static members can be modified . I mean they are part of the class even if they are static or shared between all the objects.

Comment: @KavishDwivedi they are part of class, not of object.

Comment: so const member function deals with maintaining the constness of the object. This means that even if we have a reference(int& x) as a private member, we would be able to modify it through const member function.

Answer (score 2):

> In a const member function, the object for which the function is called is accessed through a const access path; therefore, a const member function shall not modify the object and its non-static data members.

source:[someone cites c++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187746/const-method-accessing-static-variables)

As you can see, static data member is not protected by `const` as per c++ standard.